# Get the text from xml documents

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I wanted to fetch PMID, and for each PMID the list of others from authorlist, for each PMID, I could get the author list, similarly for all other PMId, I could fetch author list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PubmedArticleSet SYSTEM "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pubmed/out/pubmed_190101.dtd">
<PubmedArticleSet>
 <PubmedArticle>
<MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
  <PMID Version="1">2844048</PMID>
  <DateCompleted>
    <Year>1988</Year>
    <Month>10</Month>
    <Day>26</Day>
  </DateCompleted>
  <DateRevised>
    <Year>2010</Year>
    <Month>11</Month>
    <Day>18</Day>
  </DateRevised>
    <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Guarner</LastName>
        <ForeName>J</ForeName>
        <Initials>J</Initials>
        <AffiliationInfo>
          <Affiliation>Department of Pathology and Laboratory Medicine, Emory University Hospital, Atlanta, Georgia.</Affiliation>
        </AffiliationInfo>
      </Author>
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Cohen</LastName>
        <ForeName>C</ForeName>
        <Initials>C</Initials>
      </Author>
</AuthorList>
</MedlineCitation>
```

I can fetch individually but not getting an idea about how to group it due to the tag structure.

```
tree = ET.parse('x.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

pid =[]
for pmid in root.iter('PMID'):
   pid.append(pmid.text)

lastname=[]
for id in root.findall("./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/AuthorList"):
for ln in id.findall("./Author/LastName"):
    lastname.append(ln.text)

forename=[]
for id in root.findall("./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/AuthorList"):
for fn in id.findall("./Author/ForeName"):
    forename.append(fn.text)

initialname=[]
for id in root.findall("./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/AuthorList"):
for i in id.findall("./Author/Initials"):
   initialname.append(i.text)
```

Expected output

```
PMID               AUTHORS
2844048            'Guarner J J', 'Cohen C C'
```

Please suggest the possible way to handle the issue, the expected outputted will have more number of rows, thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you provide an example of your expected output?

Comment: please check, I have updated the question.

Comment: Your question is tagged XSLT. Your code is not XSLT. What kind of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: I have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it, though it took a while. In order to make this an interesting exercise, I made some changes.

First, the xml code in your question is invalid; [you can check it here, for example](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator).

So first I fixed the xml. In addition, I turned it into a PubmedArticleSet so it has 2 articles, the first article having 3 authors and the second - two (dummy  info, obviously), just to insure the code grabs them all. To make it somewhat simpler, I removed some irrelevant (to this exercise) information such as Affiliation.

So here's where that leaves us. 
First, modified xml:

```
source = """
<PubmedArticleSet>
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">2844048</PMID>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Guarner</LastName>
                <ForeName>J</ForeName>
                <Initials>J</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Cohen</LastName>
                <ForeName>C</ForeName>
                <Initials>C</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Mushi</LastName>
                <ForeName>E</ForeName>
                <Initials>F</Initials>
            </Author>
        </AuthorList>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">123456</PMID>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Smith</LastName>
                <ForeName>C</ForeName>
                <Initials>C</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Jones</LastName>
                <ForeName>E</ForeName>
                <Initials>F</Initials>
            </Author>
        </AuthorList>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
```

```
 """
```

Next, import what needs to be imported:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
```

Next, the code:

```
doc = etree.fromstring(source)
art_loc = '..//*/PubmedArticle' #this is the path to all the articles
#count the number of articles in the article set - that number is a float has to be converted to integer before use:
num_arts = int(doc.xpath(f'count({art_loc})')) # or could use len(doc.xpath(f'({art_loc})')) 
grand_inf = [] #this list will hold the accumulated information at the end
for art in range(1,num_arts+1): #can't do range(num_arts) because of the different ways python and Pubmed count
    loc_path = (f'{art_loc}[{art}]/*/') #locate the path to each article
    #grab the article id:
    id_path = loc_path+'PMID'
    pmid = doc.xpath(id_path)[0].text
    art_inf = [] #this list holds the information for each article
    art_inf.append(pmid)
    art_path = loc_path+'/Author' #locate the path to the author group
    #determine the number of authors for this article; again, it's a float which needs to converted to integer
    num_auths = int(doc.xpath(f'count({art_path})')) #again: could use len(doc.xpath(f'({art_path})'))

    auth_inf = [] #this will hold the full name of each of the authors

    for auth in range(1,num_auths+1):
        auth_path = (f'{art_path}[{auth}]') #locate the path to each author
        LastName = doc.xpath((f'{auth_path}/LastName'))[0].text
        FirstName = doc.xpath((f'{auth_path}/ForeName'))[0].text
        Middle = doc.xpath((f'{auth_path}/Initials'))[0].text
        full_name = LastName+' '+FirstName+' '+Middle
        auth_inf.append(full_name)
   art_inf.append(auth_inf)
   grand_inf.append(art_inf)
```

Finally, load this info into a dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(grand_inf,columns=['PMID','Author(s)'])
df
```

Output:

```
     PMID       Author(s)
 0   2844048    [Guarner J J, Cohen C C, Mushi E F]
 1   123456     [Smith C C, Jones E F]
```

And we can now rest...

Comment: num_arts = len(doc.xpath(f'({art_loc})'))), lines gives an invalid syntax error, I think due to f', it works well with Jupyter but in terminal with Python 2.7 gives an error, any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid "Python 2.7 will never support f-strings"  [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id47)...

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. Is there an alternative for python 2.7?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I believe you can replace `(f'({art_loc}))` with `('{0}'.format(art_loc))`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to replace all f string code to something in Python 3.4.2, we can't get get newer version in the server. Please suggest.

Comment: FirstName = doc.xpath((f'{auth_path}/ForeName'))[0].text, this line gives index out of range error.

Comment: @GAUTAMKISHORESHAHI - tried it again on my notebook and received no error. Can't explain the difference.

Comment: yes, on the big data, it gives an error, because all forename, initial name are of different length. I solved it suing pandas dataframe but I will happy to learn if we can solve this using the list.

Answer (score 0):

The data model of XPath 1.0 is defined in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/):

> 3.3 Node-sets
>
> 3.4 Booleans
>
> 3.5 Numbers
>
> 3.6 Strings

Node-set are proper sets: deduplicates and unordered. You want a [sequence](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-types), an ordered list o data (order list of node-set, for example). This data type is part of XPath 2.0 and after.

For grouping in XPath 1.0 as embedded language, you select the "first of its kind" and then you use the host language to trasverse the document getting the grouped items, even with another XPath expression. That is how it's done in XSLT itself.